# Matching Policy between multiple data sources in DQS

Tags: sql-server, data-quality-services

I'm New with MDS and DQS.
I'm working on DQS matching Policy.
We can create matching Policy only on a Single data Source?
My Scenario is :
If I have 2 data Sources, say PDMS and PNO.
Can we set the trust score on the Data Sources. If so,  Can we set like only the record which has highest trust score will win?
For Example :
I have data samples like

Name       Code     DataSource
ABC        1        PNO
ABD        2        PNO
ABC        3        PDMS
ABD        4        PDMS

If I set the Highest trust Score for PNO Can we get the PNO record as a leading record.
Is there any way to acieve the above criteria using DQS. Thanks!!